# Drupal website gives 404 but page is showing

Tags: php, http, drupal, http-status-code-404

I'm having some trouble with a drupal page. The website is loading and nothing is out of the ordinarty. But when you load the page with Google Chrome development shizzle (when you press F12) and put it on Network and then reload the page, you see that the first thing that happens is receive an 404 error.

[image: screenshot of Chrome dev tools]

It's not that big of a deal but our monitoring system says the website is offline because of this.

Does anyone knows what is going on? I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running into this exact problem with a D7 site on a new server that has PHP 5.5.9 installed - the page loads but the HTTP header says "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" for all pages but the homepage. If I work out a solution I'll post it here.

**Update:** It turned out my problem was that mod_rewrite was not enabled, once I enabled it the site started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal allows customizing 404-403 error pages. Probably, your site (by some reason) displays content on 403/404 pages.
At first, clear cache (using web ui or drush).
This can be 1-page issue (check /user/login, admin pages, node pages). Maybe, only your front page is not found. 
If this is not 1-page issue, check and disable customerror module (if you has one installed).